# Do all glfw functions call the error callback?

Tags: glfw

Particularly, do the functions that return `NULL` pointers in case of errors call the error callback? If that's the case and the error is handled by the callback, there would be no reason to check the return value, right?

Answer (score 0):

The [error callback](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/intro.html#error_handling) is for diagnostic purposes - not error *handling*. It is used by the internal function: `_glfwInputError` in `init.c`, which is called at various places in the GLFW library. Typically, when something like an unknown or illegal option, attribute or internal error is encountered.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. By the way, you linked to a local file in your computer. Still, does it get called if any error occurs?